# What's the best way to replace an old copy of WordPress with a fresh one and push to GitHub?

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I have been version controlling my WordPress site with Git and pushing to GitHub for quite some time. I develop locally, push to GitHub, and pull from GitHub to my production server.

I would like to scrap my current WordPress core on my local environment and replace it with a fresh new copy to then be pushed to GitHub and pulled to my production server.

My question is...am I going to run into any sort of tracking errors wit Git by replacing my WordPress core? Any other suggestions for me when I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I handle this by adding the Wordpress core as a subrepository.  WordPress maintains a mirror of their SVN repository [on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress).  Then you can update to a new version easily by going into the subdirectory containing the WordPress core files and checking out the tag for the current version:

```
git fetch --tags
git checkout 3.3.2
```

The repo also includes beta releases, if you prefer those.

Here's the guide that I used to set up this process: [Install and Manage WordPress with Git](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2012/04/09/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/)

Answer (score 0):

I understood you're talking about updating wordpress. You should note that, like documented in the [update instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress), during update you should

- check the requirements
- take a backup of your database contents
- disable the plugins you have

So all this you should do regardless. Also, you should be sure to update your database content, too, if needed.

Wordpress contains instructions on [updating using svn](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion), and it seems it is, according to them, a perfectly fine approach to have. I would see no major difference for you to do essentially the same thing with git, *provided* you can tell exactly which files are appropriate to store on version control and which aren't.